# App Acceptance Process for Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I am looking at using the Business Manager API to manage our clients Facebook advertising, including a central billing implementation, and have a few queries.

From what I can gather, to use the Business Manager API, I have to have my App accepted, then request access to the Business Manager API, then open a line of credit.

Can I develop my application in sandbox mode and get access to the Business Manager API?

How long does the process, usually, take to accept a Facebook APP, give access to the BM API and open a line of credit?

Not being able to access the BM API endpoints to manage clients and create ads hampers the development process and the ability to request the Facebook App for review.

Any help on this would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: You need to get onto the “Ads Management Standard Access” level first, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access

Comment: @CBroe So we build our app, initially, using standard API calls, get the app reviewed and accepted, then request the additional business management permissions, then update our app to use the additional functionality that the BM brings? The issue we have is that we want to centrally manage the ad payments, so we bill our clients, which requires the BM permissions. But, I suppose, we just don't release our app until we have BM access.

Comment: Yeah, I think that is the way you have to go about it. Don’t know of any other way you could test the extended BM functionalities before getting onto the AMSA level.

Comment: @CBroe No worries, I'll go down this path. Facebook API docs are quite comprehensive but I find myself going around in circles and ending up with more questions than answers. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you eventually get permission? @NealHowarth

Comment: @georgeperry We are just going through the App submission phase now. The submission is split into two, we have verified the App and business details and have had some permissions accepted. However, others are being failed for having a too high an error rate (we have 2 errors in the past 90 days!!). The process seems to be quick enough, though, usually within 24 hours we get a response.

Comment: @NealHowarth thanks for your reply. Yeah we are experiencing the same problem, specifically with the Ads Management Standard Access permission. They say they can't see "how the use of this permission directly improves the user experience in your app", but I'm struggling to find anyone else who is experiencing the same thing. Have you got any basic tips for the screencast? We are on submission 4 and still nothing - any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: @georgeperry I've not had that rejection message, yet. I created one screencast which shows everything we are using Facebook for and have submitted this same video on each permissions request; I tried to make the step by step instructions as detailed as possible for each of the specific permissions. Our video includes connecting / disconnecting the Facebook account, then, for our purposes, how we create a campaign and adset / advert etc and push this data to Facebook.

Comment: @georgeperry The Ads Management Standard Access is the permission they are rejecting us on based on a too high error rate and not enough API calls in the last 30 days. Sorry I can't be more specific, but I think it seems to depend on who is reviewing your app at the time as to the response you end up with. We are also on about the fourth submission so I'm hoping that if I keep submitting, they'll just give in and accept it :)

Comment: @NealHowarth thanks so much for the info, it makes more sense to me now. I had a feeling that the various reviewers made a big difference. We even received a rejection yesterday with a note and screenshot from the reviewer, which we had never had before. Best of luck, I will share any info if we make any more progress.

Comment: @NealHowarth Did you ever get accepted in the end? How did you get around the error rate issue?